Rust C++ FFI: How specify path for linking library files?
I'm attempting to build a Rust FFI wrapper for a C++ library using the cmake and bindgen crates. The C++ code has a supported cmake build.
When trying to build I get an error on attempting to link to the compiled C++ library.
My error is produced on running cargo test and the output is:
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcppcode: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I can see the output lib files though in the build dir, e.g.
ls ./target/debug/build/myproject-debe94b9fba6ebdb/out/lib`
libcppcode.so  libcppcode_static.a

My understanding is that the critical linking lines (in build.rs are:
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=cppcode");

But I can't seem to get the rust-link-lib to find the lib files.
For completeness, my project layout is like this:
.
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── ext
│   └── cppcode
├── src
│   └── lib.rs
└── wrapper.h

My build.rs is
extern crate cmake;
use cmake::Config;
use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main()
{
    let mut cfg = Config::new("ext/cppcode");
    let dst = cfg.build();

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=cppcode");

    // Specify the include directory for bindgen
    let include_dir = "ext/cppcode/include";

    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());

    // The bindgen::Builder is the main entry point to bindgen, and lets you build up options for the resulting bindings.
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        // The input header we would like to generate bindings for.
        .header("wrapper.h")
        // Set include directory
        .clang_arg(format!("-I{}", include_dir))
        // Finish the builder and generate the bindings.
        .generate()
        // Unwrap the Result and panic on failure.
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    // Write the bindings to the $OUT_DIR/bindings.rs file.
    bindings
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}

wrapper.h is simply:
#include "cppcode.h"

For an initial build test my lib.rs is just:
#![allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
#![allow(non_camel_case_types)]
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/bindings.rs"));

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    
    #[test]
    fn hello_test() {
        println!("Hello, tests!");   
    }
}

and my cargo.toml is:
[package]
name = "myproject"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]



[build-dependencies]
bindgen = "0.58.1"
autotools = "0.2"
cmake = "0.1.50"


What is the value of dst.display()? I suspect it's shorter than ./target/debug/build/myproject-debe94b9fba6ebdb/out/lib and that you will need to add the missing tail part yourself.

I just created a project with exactly the above files, but with the ext/cppcode folder containing a very basic cmake/cpp project, it all worked for me... however: in my case, only a static library of cppcode was built, named and located differently to yours: target/debug/build/myproject-bd9c7419240953ba/out/libcppcode.a.  This surprised me as I had expected Rust to link a dynamic library in cases such as this (link type not specified and not building a static executable). Perhaps the naming of your static library (presumably from your CMakeLists.txt file) is the issue here?

Is _static.a a standard suffix that the linker looks for? I didn't think so, I thought it was just .a and maybe an alternate extension, but I could be wrong.

Please don't edit questions to add new questions. You should open a completely new question instead.

Keys to the issue were from a combination of comments by @Jmb, @eggyal, and @kmdreko.
I needed to update build.rs to point to the build/lib directory, and to link the non-standard cppcode_static.a file.
    let dst = cfg.build();
    let lib = dst.join("lib");


    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", lib.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=cppcode_static");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=cppcode");


This now generates a new error in my project:
undefined reference to symbol '__asan_stack_malloc_0'

But this is likely due to other issues, and not due to the issue in question

Your C++ code was likely compiled with the -fsanitize=address option. You need to either remove that option from the C++ compilation, or add it to the link flags (e.g. with cargo::rustc-link-arg).

Also note if you don't recompile your C++ code, that mixing binaries compiled with and without sanitizers may lead to false positives. You may want to also compile your Rust code with sanitizer support.
